Finding relationship between saturation current and Vgs for MOSFET?
I would like to use a MOSFET to control a continuous current (i.e. by changing gate voltage), the specific MOSFET I want to use is RFD16N06LE (datasheet: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/67811/INTERSIL/RFD16N06LE.html), however the datasheet gives no relationship between drain current (at saturation or otherwise) and Vgs; can someone help please? What am I missing?

figure 7, but real values can be different... lot. Typicaly you should use some king of feedback. Search for current source (for example with opamp).

There's never a guarantee that a certain amount of current will flow, given some particular \$V_{GS}\$, because it varies so much even between devices from the same batch. Even if a datasheet does show a graph of \$I_D\$ vs. \$V_{GS}\$, that will be for some specific \$V_{DS}\$, and some specific temperature, upon both of which this relationship also heavily depends. That relationship also happens to be very non-linear.
Controlling drain current by directly adjusting gate potential is not advised, but there are some tricks you can use to do it indirectly, with better control and predictability.
The most common approach (without using an op-amp in a closed loop) is to place a resistor between source and ground. On the left is without such a resistor, and on the right that resistor, Rs, is present:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Source V1 applies a potential to the gate, and I plot the corresponding drain current here. Blue is for the left, orange right:

If the linearity and more gradual rise in current is good enough for your application, then you can determine experimentally an approximate linear equation to fit that line. As I said, though, it will be significantly different for literally every different MOSFET you try.
You may be better served by a BJT in this role, since all BJTs have a similar \$V_{BE}\$ of 0.7V or so when the transistor is in its active region. In the following schematic, the the BJT is on the right, literally dropped in place where the MOSFET would have been:

simulate this circuit
You see collector current starting to flow (orange below) as the base reaches \$V_B=0.7V\$:

\$V_{BE}\$ remains close to 0.7V in spite of further increase in base potential, and emitter potential follows the base quite closely (always 0.7V below). Even though current through Rs rises a little more linearly than for its MOSFET counterpart, the real benefit is that \$V_{BE}\approx 0.7V\$ for all silicon bipolar transistors, unlike MOSFETs, whose \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ varies wildly from device to device; I've seen \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ quoted anywhere between 0.5V and 8V. The universality of \$V_{BE}\approx 0.7V\$ means it's much easier to predict collector current \$I_C\$ as a function of base potential \$V_B\$:
$$ I_C \approx \frac{V_B - 0.7}{R_S} $$
If you require more precision, then use an op-amp:

simulate this circuit
Here the op-amp employs negative feedback to equalise its two input potentials, raising or lowering its output to exactly the correct voltage to achieve that. In other words, it will find the exact gate potential required to obtain \$V_S = V_{IN}\$. Then drain current can be predicted very precisely:
$$ I_D = \frac{V_S}{R_S} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_S} $$
This gives a perfectly linear relationship between \$V_{IN}\$ and the resulting \$I_D\$:

Choose a value for \$R_S\$ (according to the above equation) to obtain some relationship between \$I_D\$ and \$V_{IN}\$ (the slope), and then set \$V_{IN}\$ for any drain current you desire, within the limits of the design of course.

Hi, thanks for the help, I've used an Op amp as you suggested, but in order to get the required current I needed r2 = 0, I built an LTspice model that said this was fine, but now I've built it I'm getting much lower current than needed (0.07A instead of 2A), the op amp + input voltage is correct, but the output im getting is around 12V (i.e. near the max for my power supply, the LTSpice model says it should by 3.25V, could you suggest what might be the issue please?

@Dip R2 represents any load you want to put there. Replace R2 with your load. Even a load of 0Ω, you'll still have 500mA flowing through it (using the values I showed). Sorry if I didn't make that clear. However, there is a maximum possible load resistance: $R=\frac{V}{I}=\frac{12V}{500mA}=24\Omega$.

@Dip for $I_D=2A$, you can't use a load greater than about 5Ω, unless you increase supply voltage. You can't get more current than you would get by connecting the load directly across the supply. For instance if you require 2A through a 20Ω load, the supply has to be at least $V=IR=2A\times 20\Omega=40V$, even more, since $R_S$ eats up some of that voltage.
