Switching regulator issues?
I'm trying to use a switching regulator (ptr08060w) to step 12V DC down to 2V DC, however it is not achieving this at all (even with no load connected), and is outputting a voltage that varies randomly between 0.6 V -> 1.6 V, sometimes oscillating, sometimes steady at one of the incorrect voltages, sometime is starts to work (outputting a stead 2V), but then stops again after a random time. The voltages at the other pins of the regulator are constant, regardless of whether it is behaving or not.
This is related to my other question, in which the regulator's output was changing only under load, I realized I had wired the op-amp incorrectly, causing the MOSFET to open too much, causing to much current; I fixed this and it worked fine from there until this issue arose.
It's not overheating (at least, it doesn't feel hot at all on my finger), does anyone have any ideas what else could be causing this?

UPDATE: Ok it seems to be working now (I did nothing) but my question still stands
UPDATE 2: nvm it's not working again - perhaps it's a connection problem? this is my first time using a vero board so all my solders are pretty bad :(
Pics of circuit (ik it's bad it was my first time):



Put a schematic. Layout and a photo of the whole setup help as well.

Dip - Hi, This is a slightly different problem description to your question from yesterday, as you are now saying the output voltage fluctuation occurs even without a load (yesterday, you said it only occurred with a load). However, when you're posting questions that are clearly related, it's important that you include details that are missing from here: Mention & link to relevant previous questions, and explain why later questions are not duplicates. Explain what is different, what you have changed etc. So while each question should be "standalone", don't hide the context. TY

@RohatKılıç , Done


What are the  PN#s of the capacitors you used? 2) Have you tried to apply a steady-state load (aka no PWM)?


@Dip - Thanks for adding more info. However the "it's working", "now it's not working" updates suggest there could be a more fundamental issue, which is difficult to diagnose remotely e.g. the soldering concerns which you mentioned. I suggest you consider adding photos of the actual hardware with close-ups of the soldering, as that might allow people here to spot problems. But it can be very difficult to identify some poor solder joints remotely,

@RogerDodger capacitors are these:  https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/aluminium-capacitors/0570966?gb=s  as recommended in the datasheet; using steady state 5V input lead to the same results

@Dip what I mean is remove the PWM circuit, and put different values of resistors (from max load to min load) and see if your output voltage can regulate

I suspect the issue could be around your comparator. Just by curiosity, why are you using a comparator? I think it's creating an argument, so to speak, with your Arduino and the output source pin of the FET on who should drive the PWM.

@Colin But the issue is still there even when that whole part of the circuit is disconnected from the regulator; I'm using an op-amp so it maintains the same current through the heating element even as it changes resistance, similar to as described by Simon Fitch's answer to this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719918/finding-relationship-between-saturation-current-and-vgs-for-mosfet

@Dip I see... Interesting.  Apologies, I didn't review your other question you linked before. Are you measuring at the source pin of the FET?
